# How to check for installed libraries e.g. libpcap when installing software using gnu make?

Tags: makefile, gnu-make

I am developing an application which depends on libpcap and want to know how to write the gnu makefile such that i can check for installation of libpcap on a machine before proceeding with the installation of my application.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If libpcap supports it, you might try using [pkg-config](http://pkg-config.freedesktop.org/wiki/). (I know that libpcap++ supports it, but not sure about libpcap). That said, if you don't already have an established build system, then I suggest you try using [CMake](http://www.cmake.org/) which makes this kind of thing and all other aspects of creating a C++ project significantly simpler. For an example or getting started quickly using CMake, see the C++ Project Template.

Answer (score 0):

If I were going to answer your question properly I'd look at how autoconf checks for the existence of components when I install a package such as GNUPlot (or whatever) and figure it out.  I'll leave the work to you though.